# typescript/ecmascript: proper default typed export syntax

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6, react-functional-component

## Problem

`React.FC` view with props

```
import React from 'react';

const unwanted_string_that_i_want_to_drop: React.FC<{
    userName: string;
}> = (props) => (
    <span>Hello, {props.userName}</span>
);

export default unwanted_string_that_i_want_to_drop;
```

**How to drop `unwanted_string_that_i_want_to_drop`** ?

(make "oneliner", default(unnamed), typed export for one of most frequent tasks)

## Reasoning

Obviusly, name should be defined defined at the importer side, who will setup and manage required arrangement by himself. view does not have to export anything other than view - named exports are not needed here.

## Tried solutions

### `as` in the end:

```
import React from 'react';

export default ((props) => (
    <span>Hello, {props.userName}</span>
)) as React.FC<{
    userName: string;
}>;
```

1. it is more straightforward to define type at the head (not in the a$$ of the end of world),
2. it does not work, showing some crap like `is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes`

Comment: Why not `export default function ...`?

Comment: will do that. anyway why its not possiblt to type `default: FC<>` or some syntax allowing typing default? also i cannot `do const default: FC<>= ...` default it says a reserved name or something like that